# AngularJS: TypeError: Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

Probably I completely don't understand Angular. My question is:

On UI I have following:

```
 <input ng-model="$ctrl.newItem.action" id="action" name="action" class="form-control"/>
```

So `action` element is two-ways binded to angular model.

Now in the other part of UI but with the same controller I call edit method:

```
 $ctrl.updateItem = function (item) {
            $ctrl.newItem.action = item.action;
            //...
```

I would like `$ctrl.newItem.action` show action of currently being edited element bu instead i see error in console:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property of undefined
```

Why `$ctrl.newItem.action` is undefined?

Comment: try removing $ctrl in the html view

Comment: hint: it's not complaining `$ctrl.newItem.action` being undefined, it is complaining `$ctrl.newItem` being undefined.

Comment: if we see sample of the code you're trying to implement, where did you write `$ctrl.newItem.action = item.action;` ? inside the controller function ?

Comment: maybe `$ctrl.newItem` is not initialized, and the call for `$ctrl.updateItem` happening before any thing else.

Comment: @Icycool, got it! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular models undefined until you define it in controller or type something in input

try this one

```
$ctrl.updateItem = function (item) {
            $ctrl.newItem = {action: item.action};
            //...
```

Answer (score 0):

from what i understood is that you're trying to access a variable in the controller but you get an error that the variable is undefined, so if this is the case you have to make sure of the following:

-in the view don't add the service or the controller name or anything else, just the variable name, Ex (HTML CODE):

```
<input ng-model="newItem.action" id="action" name="action" class="form-control"/>
```

-make sure u added the $scope service in the controller, and attach the variable name to it Ex (JS CODE):

```
app.controller(function($scope){
$scope.newItem=...
});
```

-the variable `newItem` should be attached to the scope service in the controller like this:

```
$scope.newItem = {action:"awesomeAction"};
```

or at least:
`$scope.newItem = {};` (in this case angularjs will create the parameter ".action" automatically)